# React application deployed on azure is not using Http2 even though Http2.0 is enabled for app service on azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, http2, azure-appservice

I have deployed my react application on Azure App Service with .NET Stack (.NET Core 3.1,2.1). I have enabled Http2.0 from **Azure App Service > Configuration > General Settings** and also from **azure resource explorer**. At both places it shows Http2.0 but browser still uses Http1.1. TLS Settings are Https only and TLS version 1.2

Comment: Are you using a component in front of the App Service like Front Door or Application Gateway? These would require HTTP/2 to be enabled as well.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole Yes, we were using WAF and that was not supporting Http2.0. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In front of the APP service WAF was enabled. And WAF was not supporting Http2.0

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with this function.

**I reproduced your problem. You only need to open a new privacy mode window and refresh it a few times to see the new settings take effect.**

This problem may be caused by browser cache, etc.

## **Test Result.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]